# Battery drain after update?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, battery

bq Aquaris E5 HD Ubuntu Edition. I have just applied 15.04 update. I haven't used the phone today and I am below 50% half way through the day after a full charge at night. Usually the phone is incredibly efficient with a need to charge every other day with quite a lot of usage.
The only other thing I have changed is the wallpaper since the update.
Just wondering if anyone was seeing a similar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Update seemed to turn my GPS on - switched off
changed wallpaper back to Ubuntu from photo
rebooted

My phone is now back to being brilliant again